# How to display mongo db case sensitive data using regex in symfony2

Tags: php, regex, mongodb, symfony

I am executing a search on ajax call. I want all the data to be displayed in the table format ignoring the case sensitiveness of the word typed in search box.

Example:

Whether user type 'd' or 'D' it should display all the data contained "demo/Demo" word in it.

I have tried on this query in symfony2:

```
$clientDetails = $dm->getRepository('AuditSuperFirmClientBundle:FirmClient')->findBy(array('clientCompanyName' => array('$regex' => $name)));
```

But this display case sensitive data. If i type 'D' it is not displaying the data of 'demo'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For regex queries you should use `QueryBuilder` (the ODM one). Here's the documentation article: http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html Since there's no `LIKE` operator in Mongo you'll have to create query like this:

```
$qb->field($field)->equals(new \MongoRegex('/.*demo.*/i'));
```

Notice the `i` flag as that's what makes the query case insensitive.

Comment: but i am using mongo db with this. Will this work with mongo?

Comment: blank table is there no result found :(

Comment: could you provide the exact code you're using? Preferably from the beggining ot QueryBuilder to the flush, or an entire function/method if not too long.

Comment: $name = $request->get('fundName');
        $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();

        $qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('AuditSuperFirmClientBundle:FirmClient');
        $clientDetails = $qb->field('clientCompanyName')->equals(new \MongoRegex('/'.$name.'/i'))->getQuery()
            ->execute();

        return $this->render('AuditSuperFirmClientBundle:FirmClient:Firmclient.html.twig', array(
                'clientDetails'=> $clientDetails,
            ));

Comment: you forgot the `.*` before and after $name. should look like this:
`$clientDetails = $qb->field('clientCompanyName')->equals(new \MongoRegex('/.*'.$name.'.*/i'))->getQuery() ->execute();` The `.*` part indicates the `$name` can be just a part of a string. Without it it matches only exact `$name` string..